# How to install Intel SGX platform software?

Tags: sgx

I have tried to install the platform software (PSW) many times on my Windows machine and failed.

I have tried to install it on the following OS version (all 64 bits)

```
Windows 10 Pro build 1803
Windows 10 Pro build 1809
Windows 10 Home build 1809
Windows 10 Home build 1803
```

According to the release note, PSW is supposed to support the following OS

```
Windows 10 Nov Update (1511)
Windows 10 Anniversary update (1607)
Windows 10 Creators Update (1703)
Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (1709)
Windows 10 Spring Creators Update (1803)
```

The error is

“Operating system “Windows 10 Home 10.0.17134” is not supported” or
“Operating system “Windows 10 Pro xxxxxx is” is not supported”

My processor is 8700k and I am using gigabyte Z370 Aorus Ultra Gaming F4 bios, which supports SGX. I turned the bios option on and verified by SGX-test.c

It’s very frustrating since I built the entire machine for this purpose. Did I miss anything?

Comment: [Intel® Software Guard Extensions (Intel® SGX)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-software-guard-extensions-intel-sgx) is where your question supposedly belongs to. Perhaps you want to try newer/older PSW version. I personally have my dev machine with i7-8700K CPU, Asus Z370-E mobo and I have PSW 2.1.100.46245 installed on Win 10 Pro 1809 and working.

Comment: I guess [this topic's #2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-software-guard-extensions-intel-sgx/topic/783961#comment-1925699) answers your question directly.